# UIDocumentBrowserViewController app : Refresh no of items in each folder

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentbrowserviewcontroller

I am creating an UIDocumentBrowser based app and notice this issue:

- Say I am viewing these folders:-
  Folder 1 -> 20 items
  Folder 2 -> 50 items
  ....

e.g If my app deletes all items in say Folder 2, "50 items" is still listed as in Folder 2. How to force a refresh so that the no. of items show the correct "0 items"??

Thanks

Edited to add screenshots with issue.
I create a "dummy" UIDocumentBrowser app to show the issue.
In the app, I added a button to delete "Selected files".

[Initial state with folder F1 8 items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXpae.png)

[Screenshot with selection of 8 items in folder F1 and then choosing the "Test-Delete" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8AQm.png)

[All files are deleted in folder F1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlddw.png)

[Go back one folder up and folder F1 still says 8 items!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSgom.png)

[Go up one more folder and then back down, and folder F1 correctly shows 0 items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK9V1.png)

The code to delete the items is:-

```
func Delete_button_action(documentURLs: [URL]) {
    for item in documentURLs {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: item)
            print("Item=\(item) deleted")
        } catch {
            print("Error in removing item \(item); error=\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could this be a bug report to Apple?